# Quicker way to get date of ISO week from a date string?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm being passed a date string (most likely in ISO8601 format) and need to convert it to the date of the ISO week to store as a DATETIME column in MySQL. To initialize the DateTime object the I want to save, I'm doing the following:

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
$date = new DateTime( $date->format("o-\WW") );

echo $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";
```

Since I'm using Doctrine2, I need to pass my entity a DateTime object. Is there a way to avoid making 2 DateTime objects to get the same result? Should I drop back to the date function and use that as the argument to the DateTime constructor?

```
$date = new DateTime( date("o-\WW", strtotime("now") );
```

Comment: `$date = new DateTime( $date->format("o-\WW") S);` What does the S do?

Comment: @HorseSMith Nothing, that was a typo when I was formatting my question. I have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `modify()` method of `DateTime` object.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('sunday this week');
echo $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";
```

Note that if you want the first day of the week to be something other than Sunday, you will likely need to do something like the following.  This example considers Monday as the first day of the week, thus for dates on a Sunday, you would need to get the date of the Monday from the previous week.

```
$date = new DateTime();
if ($date->format('D') === 'Sun') {
    $date->modify('monday last week');
} else {
    $date->modify('monday this week');
}
echo $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";
```

Comment: @Glavić It is good to point out this edge condition. I am not sure if this is desired behavior or not.  The OP should consider what they want to first day of the week to be defined as.  They should also be consistent with any usage of `WEEK()` function they might use in MySQL to retrieve the week number as the "mode" being used will impact the expected results.  I have updated my answer to make this edge case more clear.

Comment: @Glavić You are correct.  The context I took from it was that he only cared about ISO-8601 format so as to make recordation in MySQL easier.  It does not seem clear to me from the question that he is trying to apply that standard to the determination for the start of the week.  At any rate, thanks for adding your comments in this regard as it is still important that OP understand the different ways for handling weeks.  The are also considerations around the year barriers that might need to come into play depending on how he might end up using the week information in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `setISODate` to update the first `DateTime` object using the week and year of the object via `format()`:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($date->format('o') , $date->format('W'));
echo $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: First parameter of the method `setISODate()` should be ISO year number. If ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, year of that week should be used. Good example is 2013-12-30 and 2013-12-31 which are already in week one of the year 2014. [See demo](https://eval.in/57726).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code. I misread the format character descriptions and thought that 'Y' returned the ISO year. Was aware of the potential, but used the wrong code anyway. :p

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) like this:

```
$date = new DateTime( date('o-\WW') );
```

Though that formatting looks a bit strange. :p You can of course also use some other method/function the class has to offer to change/modify the date.

Comment: I just used "now" as an example. In my actual code, the "now" is pulling a parameter from the request object.

Comment: "now" means right at this moment, not an earlier or later date, it's NOW. <_< date() without the time() parameter should be fine then. Yes, your example somewhat says otherwise, but just somewhat. I do suggest, and still mean it, you should use the API for the DateTime class to see if there is any good methods/functions to use in this situation, which there was. In any case, pointless if you could just do what I said above.